# how does the cross-validation work in learning curve? Python sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Say I have a learning curve that is [sklearn learning curve SVM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syTe2.png). And I'm also doing 5-fold cross-validation, which as far as I understand, it means splitting your **training** data into 5 pieces, train on four of them and testing on the last one.

So my question is, since for each data point in the `LearningCurve`, the size of the training set is different (Because we want to see how will the model perform with the increasing amount of data), how does the cross-validation work in that case? Does it still split the whole training set into 5 equal pieces? Or it splits the current point training set into five different small pieces, then computes the test score? Is it possible to get a confusion matrix for each data point? (i.e. True Positive, True Negative etc.). I don't see a way to do that yet based on the sklearn learning curve code.

Does how many folds of cross-validation relate to how many pieces of training set we are splitting in `train_sizes = np.linspace(0.1, 1.0, 5)`.

```
train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores, fit_times, _ = learning_curve(estimator,
                                                                      X, y, cv, 
                                                                      n_jobs, scoring, 
                                                                      train_sizes)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does the split the training data into 5 folds again. Instead, for a particular combination of training folds (for example - folds 1,2,3 and 4 as training), it will pick only k number of data points (x- ticks) as training from those 4 training folds. Test fold would be used as such as the testing data.

If you look at the code [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/fd237278e/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L1275) it would become clearer for you.

```
for train, test in cv_iter:
     for n_train_samples in train_sizes_abs:
          train_test_proportions.append((train[:n_train_samples], test))
```

`n_train_samples` would be something like `[200,400,...1400]` for the plot that you had mentioned.

> Does how many folds of cross-validation relate to how many pieces of training set we are splitting in train_sizes = np.linspace(0.1, 1.0, 5)?

we can't assign any number of folds for a certain `train_sizes`. It is just a subset of datapoints from all the training folds.

Comment: What does it mean by ticks? I also saw the learning curve page says "train_scores array of shape (n_ticks, n_cv_folds)". Do you mind explaining that too?

Comment: ticks is the number of unique values in the x-axis of your plot. It would be nothing but the `n_train_samples` in my answer. `train_scores` is 2d array with rows represent the `n_train_samples` and column represent the each combination of CV folds. If you are using 5fold cross validation, then you will get 5 different combinations of train and test data split. These would be represented in the column of `train_scores`.

Comment: Shouldn't the size of the test set held constant?